# Relationship between close votes and Review Queue

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

I usually don't pay much attention as to how the Review Queue behaves, but today I found the following situation:

This question has 2 Close Votes:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, while I expect the question to be found in my Review Queue, it is empty:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So ... when does the closing votes "enter" the Review Queue?

Comment: [That one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47079/number-of-gelfand-tsetlin-patterns-np-complete) is already deleted (by the owner).  Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: @Szabolcs It wasn't when I took the snapshots. See Shog9's answer below!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Review is only updated every 5 minutes. In addition, the oldest vote must be at least 15 minutes old before it is even *eligible* for review: a lot of problems resolve themselves, so putting them up for review would just be a waste of time.

In this case, the author himself deleted the question before it was ever added to review.

Comment: That should be it! Thanks!

Comment: Another occasional problem is old questions on which one has already voted to close.